# jQuery update razor "if" statement

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following HTML:

```
@if (Model.emailhasbeensent != true) 
{ 
<div id="MailFoot">            
<input id="input1" class="form-control" type="email" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="emailSignup">Signup</button></div>
}

else {
<div id="ty" style="display:none">
<p>Thank you for subscribing </p>
</div>
}
```

When my email form is submitted, an ajax script calls my controller and updates `Model.emailhasbeensent` (it is being set to true). However, the page doesn't refresh, which means that the view doesn't show the "Thank you for subscribing" text. Instead the email submit form persists.

I thought that i could put some `<div>` tags around my razor "if" statement and then `.load` the divs in jquery on submit.

It does however not work.

How can i update `Model.emailhasbeensent` and make my if statement show "thank you for subscribing", without updating the entire page?

i could do something like:

```
$("#emailSignup").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "@Url.Action("EmailSend", "Home")",
            data: { input1: $('#input1').val(), __RequestVerificationToken:$('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val() },
    success: function () {
        $("#MailFoot").css({"display":"none"});
        $("#ty").removeAttr("style");
    }
```

but that is a solution i really don't fancy, as it doesn't take my property `emailhasbeensent` into consideration. - Obviously because i want the session to remember the setting, even though the page is refreshed.

Controller:

```
    public void EmailSend(string input1)
    {

        EmailSignup person = new EmailSignup { emailhasbeensent = false, Email = input1 };
        if(person.emailhasbeensent != true){

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mail", "password");

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress("mail");
        message.To.Add(person.Email);
        message.Subject = "Thank you for subscribing";
        message.Body = "You have now subscribed for our newsletter";
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        client.Send(message);
        person.emailhasbeensent = true;
        }
        else { }
    }
```

Model:

```
public class EmailSignup
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool emailhasbeensent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you should return Model.emailhasbeensent  from controller to ajax call and check in success handler.

Comment: `success: function () {
                if(@Model.emailhasbeensent == true){
                    $("#MailFoot").css({"display":"none"});
                }`

You mean something like this?

Comment: you have to pass email flag from controller from MVC side as JSONResult and then in ajax you can fetch as follow success: function (data) { if(data.emailhasbeensent == true){ $("#MailFoot").css({"display":"none"}); }

Comment: can  you show controller code as well ?

Comment: yes! i will update my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are making an ajax call to invoke the method which sends the email. In that case, have your server method returns a json response value indicating whether the operation was successful or not and let the javascript which handles the callback check this value and hide/show the appropriate div for the message.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EmailSend(string input1)
{
  try
   {
       //your existing code to send email
      return Json(new { status="success"});
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      // to do :Log error
      return Json(new { status="error"});
   }

}
```

and in the client side code, when you get a response back from your ajax call check the status property and hide and show the appropriate div. You can use the `done()` event on the `$.ajax` method.

```
$("#emailSignup").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "@Url.Action("EmailSend", "Home")",
            data: { input1: $('#input1').val(), __RequestVerificationToken:$('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val() },
            }).done(function(res){
                 if(res.status==="success")
                 {
                   $("#MailFoot").hide();
                   $("#ty").show();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    alert("Error sending email");
                 }
              });
});
```

Since you are doing an ajax post and updating the DOM element visibility using client side javascript, you do not need the if condition on your razor code. Any C# code on razor file will be executed at server while client side code executes on browser.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately im not sure how i would do this. Im fairly new at this. I made this in my ajax:
            `success: function () {
                if("@Model.emailhasbeensent" != true){
                    $("#MailFoot").css({"display":"none"});
                }
                }`

Comment: that makes really good sense, does that mean that i basically move my success / error in my ajax post to my controller for it to determine?

Comment: doesn't it need JSONresult/ActionResult as return type then bool ?

Comment: @jjj Yes. Fixed now. Thanks

Comment: @JeppeChristensen You check the status property value in your success callback and hide/show the div

Answer (score 0):

try following - server method return after sending email - you can return string as well. and then success call returned flag and  update dom.

```
 public JsonResult EmailSend(string input1)
{

    return Json(person.emailhasbeensent, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}


success: function (data) { 
if(data == true)
{ 
   $("#MailFoot").css({"display":"none"}); 
}
```